# Second extra info in moderncv

Tags: miktex, moderncv

Currently, I'm doing my CV (résumé) with Miktek 2.9, `moderncv` v2.0.0. In the header, I want to add two extra infos (The fact that I'm single and my date of birth). The first extra info I can add with `\extrainfo{}`. How about the second? How can I define a second extra info, called for example `\extrainfoo{}`?

Here is a short compatible code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvicons{marvosym}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}
\def\Cplusplus{C\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny\textbf{++}}}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\hfil}
 {\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
 {}
 {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
 {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
 {}
 {}
\name{Anthony}{HAUSER}
\title{}
\address{Street}{City}{}
\phone[mobile]{phone number}
\extrainfo{Age (Date of birth)}
\extrainfoo{Single}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Formation}
\cventry{9.2014--présent}{Diplome}{Ecole}{Lieu}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, style `banking` handles `\extrainfo` in another way than for example `classic` or `casual`.

A look into the code of style `banking` shows, that this style adds entrys to the header with `~~~\textbullet~~~`.

In your case the easiest way is to use

```
\extrainfo{Age (Date of birth)~~~\textbullet~~~Single}
```

that adds the extra information two you wants using the given layout ...

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}

\moderncvicons{marvosym}
\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}

\def\Cplusplus{C\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny\textbf{++}}}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\hfil}
 {\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
 {}
 {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
 {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
 {}
 {}
\name{Anthony}{HAUSER}
\title{}
\address{Street}{City}{}
\phone[mobile]{077 410 08 92}
\extrainfo{Age (Date of birth)~~~\textbullet~~~Single} % <===================
%\extrainfoo{Single}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Formation}
\cventry{9.2014--présent}{Diplome}{Ecole}{Lieu}{}{}
\end{document}
```

gives the result:

[image]

This way omits to patch the original code of class `moderncv`...

**Edit:**

If you want to patch the class you have to add the following code (if version of class `moderncv` changes it could be that this code has to be reworked!):

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\newcommand*{\extrainfoo}[1]{\def\@extrainfoo{#1}}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
 {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}}
 {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfoo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfoo}}}
 {}
 {failure} % to get an error message if failure ...
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

This code adds `\extrainfoo` if it is defined, concatenated with the definded sign dividing severel parts from each other ...

Of course you have now to define `\extrainfoo` in your code.

Please see the complete changed MWE (relevant changes marked with `<======`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{black}

\moderncvicons{marvosym}
\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}

\def\Cplusplus{C\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny\textbf{++}}}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\hfil}
 {\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
 {}
 {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
 {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
 {}
 {}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\newcommand*{\extrainfoo}[1]{\def\@extrainfoo{#1}}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
 {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}}
 {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfoo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfoo}}}
 {}
 {}
\makeatother % <========================================================

\name{Anthony}{HAUSER}
\title{}
\address{Street}{City}{}
\phone[mobile]{077 410 08 92}
\extrainfo{Age (Date of birth)}
\extrainfoo{Single} % <=================================================

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Formation}
\cventry{9.2014--présent}{Diplome}{Ecole}{Lieu}{}{}
\end{document}
```

with the same result I showed above with the first code ...